# CMake project depending on another CMake project unresolved symbols

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following CMake project which compiles no problem on visual studio and macos.

```
#specify minimum cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

# name the project (can retreive this using ${PROJECT_NAME})
project(GLbase)

# specify any specific flags we want (here we are just requiring at least C++11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# set up some variables, holds the location of source, include, dependencies, and test directories.
set(SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
set(INC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set(TEST_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests")
set(LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies")

# our library files.
set(SOURCE_FILES    "${SRC_DIR}/Error.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/GLSLShader.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/Renderer.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/Utils.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/GLbase.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/Texture.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/imgui/imgui_demo.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/imgui/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp"
                    "${SRC_DIR}/imgui/imgui.cpp")

set(HEADER_FILES    "${INC_DIR}/Binding.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/Drawable.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/Error.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/GLSLShader.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/Renderer.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/Utils.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/GLbase.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/Texture.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/stb_image.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/imconfig.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/imgui_impl_glfw.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/imgui_internal.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/imgui.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/imstb_rectpack.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/imstb_textedit.h"
                    "${INC_DIR}/imstb_truetype.h")

# create the library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})
# where are the includes for the library.
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${INC_DIR}")
# dont add lib prefix on macOS
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

# Dependencies
# GLFW
set(GLFW_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glfw")
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW example programs")
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW test programs")
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW documentation")
set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Generate installation target")
add_subdirectory("${GLFW_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "glfw" "${GLFW_LIBRARIES}")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${GLFW_DIR}/include")
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE")

# glad
set(GLAD_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glad")
add_library("glad" STATIC "${GLAD_DIR}/src/glad.c")
target_include_directories("glad" PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "glad" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")

# glm
set(GLM_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glm")
add_subdirectory("${GLM_DIR}")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${GLM_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "glm" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")

# assimp
set(ASSIMP_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/assimp")
add_subdirectory("${ASSIMP_DIR}")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${ASSIMP_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "assimp" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
```

and then i have the following project which uses the above library as a dependency.

```
#specify minimum cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

# name the project (can retreive this using ${PROJECT_NAME})
project(GLBaseExample)

# specify any specific flags we want (here we are just requiring at least C++11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(ROOT_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(GL_BASE_DIR "${ROOT_DIR}/gl-base")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ROOT_DIR}/example/Test.cpp)

add_subdirectory(${GL_BASE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "GLbase" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${GL_BASE_DIR}/include")
```

Project structure is

```
ROOT
    - GLbase
        - ....
        - CMakeLists.txt

    - Example
         - Test.cpp

    - CMakeLists.txt # CMakeLists for Example/Test.cpp
```

When I try to compile the Example project, I get unresolved symbols for every call to the GLbase library, what am I missing here?

Comment: Is "gl-base" the right folder name ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Why are the libraries not linked publicly? Also where does this variable come from and why do you use quotes around a variable that indicates that it contains a list of multiple libs? In case there are indeed multiple libs you don't want them to be treated as a single lib: `"${GLFW_LIBRARIES}"`